# Create a predicate that returns lists that meet certain conditions

Tags: list, prolog

I was trying to create a predicate `example(N, L)`, where `L` is a list that for given N:

- has length 2*N
- every number from 1 to N is to be found exactly twice
- between two appearences of the same number, there is an even number of other numbers

Also, before appearence of number n, we expect every number from {1, ..., n-1} to appear at least once

For example,

```
`?- example(3, L).
L = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3] ;
L = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2] ;
L = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3] ;
L = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] ;`
```

So my idea was to create a list like 1_2_3_...n_, filling all "_" with permutations of n-sized set. For N = 2, I would get 1 1 2 2, 1 2 2 1 meeting all conditions. I tried a lot of times, but still have no idea how to create such a structure in SWI. I would appreciate any hint, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can share your existing code attempt, other users may be able to fill in the gaps.

Comment: You should use `clpfd` library to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

To give you an idea on how to solve this task using `clpfd` library, i wrote part of the solution:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

gapBetweenElements(_,C,N):-
    C > N.
gapBetweenElements(L,C,N):-
    C =< N,
    N1 #< N2,
    N2 - N1 #= T,
    T rem 2 #= 1,
    element(N1,L,C),
    element(N2,L,C),
    C1 is C+1,
    gapBetweenElements(L,C1,N).

countElement([],_,[]).
countElement([H|T],E,[HB|TB]):-
    HB in 0..1,
    H #= E #<==> HB #= 1,
    countElement(T,E,TB).

occurrencesNumber(_,C,N,_):-
    C > N.
occurrencesNumber(L,C,N,Times):-
    C =< N,
    countElement(L,C,LB),
    sum(LB,#=,Times),
    C1 is C+1,
    occurrencesNumber(L,C1,N,Times).

applyDomain([],_).
applyDomain([H|T],V):-
    H in 1..V,
    applyDomain(T,V).

example(N,L):-
    Len is 2*N,
    length(L,Len),
    applyDomain(L,N),
    occurrencesNumber(L,1,N,2),
    gapBetweenElements(L,1,N),
    label(L).
```

With `length/2` you constrain the list to be made of `Len` elements. With `applyDomain/2` you can set the domain for each element (in this case, from `1` to `N`). With `occurrencesNumber/4` you constraint the list to contain each element, exactly two times (note that, to count the element in the list, i used `countElement/3` wich counts each element using reification variables. This might not be the best solution because reification varibles don't do much propagation...). With  `gapBetweenElements/3` you impose that the gap between same elements must be even. Finally with `label/1`, you can search for the solution.

```
?- example(3,L).
L = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
L = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
L = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3]
L = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2]
and so on...
```

Now you need to implement the last constraint, as you said: "before appearence of number n, we expect every number from {1, ..., n-1} to appear at least once".